How can I write a jq expression to convert nested array objects in JSON to a JSON schema?
I have a JSON structure like this:
{
"objectSchema": {
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID",
            "domain": null,
            "editable": false,
            "nullable": false,
            "defaultValue": null,
            "modelName": "OBJECTID"
        },
        {
            "name": "ENABLED",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
            "alias": "ENABLED",
            "domain": {
                "type": "codedValue",
                "name": "EnabledDomain",
                "description": "Geometric Network Enabled domain",
                "codedValues": [
                    {
                        "name": "False",
                        "code": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "True",
                        "code": 1
                    }
                ],
                "mergePolicy": "esriMPTDefaultValue",
                "splitPolicy": "esriSPTDefaultValue"
            },
            "editable": true,
            "nullable": true,
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "modelName": "ENABLED"
        },
        {
            "name": "GLOBALID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeGlobalID",
            "alias": "GLOBALID",
            "domain": null,
            "editable": false,
            "nullable": false,
            "length": 38,
            "defaultValue": null,
            "modelName": "GLOBALID"
        }
    ]
   }
   }

My current jq -
def convertToSchema: if type == "array" then if length == 0 then {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}} else {"type": "array", "items": (reduce map(convertToSchema)[] as $i ({}; . *= $i))} end elif type == "object" then {"type": "object", "properties": map_values(convertToSchema)} elif type == "boolean" then {"type": "boolean"} elif type == "number" then {"type": "number"} elif type == "string" then {"type": "string"} elif type == "null" then {"type": "string"} else {"type": (type | tostring)} end; .objectSchema | convertToSchema

My current output / converted JSON schema -
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"fields": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "alias": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "domain": {
        "type": "string",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "codedValues": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "code": {
                  "type": "number"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "mergePolicy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "splitPolicy": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "editable": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "nullable": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "defaultValue": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "modelName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "length": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}

Here "domain" field should be of "type": "object", but while converting it to schema in output I am getting it as "type": "string".
Please give me a proper jq expression that will handle above situations in all JSON nested object cases and ensure that each item in the array is considered and merged properly before applying the convertToSchema function and  create a combined schema that includes all unique properties from all items in the array.
Providing JQPlay link with proper solution will be more helpful.

Instead of add, you need to merge with * operator:
jq '
def convertToSchema:
  if type == "array" then
    if length == 0 then {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}}
    else {"type": "array", "items":
          (reduce map(convertToSchema)[] as $i ({}; . *= $i))}
    end
  elif type == "object" then {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": map_values(convertToSchema)}
  elif type == "boolean" then {"type": "boolean"}
  elif type == "number" then {"type": "number"}
  elif type == "string" then {"type": "string"}
  elif type == "null" then {"type": "string"}
  else {"type": (type | tostring)} end;
.objectSchema | convertToSchema
' input.json

Output:
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fields": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fieldArray": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "a": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "c": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "x": {
                "type": "number"
              },
              "y": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


its handling nested part but schema conversion is incorrect.
I am updating my JSON in question again, see generated output its giving "type": "string" instead of giving "type": "object" to "domain" field

Hi @Philippe I have updated my query / issue in question causing because of your provided jq.
Please provide solution to handle it.

Here is the JQPlay link for your reference - https://jqplay.org/s/NaZWJ7RTsj7nazf

That's because you have "domain":null in your data. You can try elif type == "null" then empty which generates correct conversion in this particular case, but may not work in other situations.

can you please provide a JQ that will handle these type of fields that may have different types in nested array objects ?

Given that your data contains both "domain": null and "domain": {...}, what's your desired output ?

In nested arrays if there are fields like "domain" present in JSON where its type may change in multiple records like above example then, It should neglect "null" and take appropriate type i.e "{...}". JQ should be able to handle any such fields like 'domain'.

Hi @Philippe any update on above requirement ?

Have not found a solution yet.

Ok. I tried elif type == "null" then empty but this is removing fields which are null. This I dont want, so I am converting "null" to "string".
Please try to give some solution @Philippe so I can go ahead, currently I am totally blocked due to this.

There is a simple but generic "structural schema inference engine"
at https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed (schema.jq).
It produces a schema very similar to the one you describe (see below),
but if that is not directly acceptable, you could either add a filter
to convert it to the form you want, or tweak schema.jq itself.
With schema.jq in the pwd ("."), and using your file as input.json:
< input.json jq 'include "schema" {search: "."}; schema'

produces:
{
  "objectSchema": {
    "fields": {
      "fieldArray": [
        {
          "a": "string",
          "c": "string",
          "x": "number",
          "y": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



Notes:

schema.jq is compatible with both gojq and jaq (the Go and Rust implementations of jq), but at the time of writing, jaq does does support the include statement.  You could however leave schema.jq untouched by writing something like:

< input.json jaq -f <(cat schema.jq; echo schema) 


Disclaimer: schema.jq was written by yours truly.

